# add html only once on button click

Tags: jquery

I'm injecting some html, a span tag to display an error message, on a button click.  I only want to add the html once.  Every time the button is clicked it add the html again.  How can I add the html only once?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        var submitButton = j$('[id$=btnSubmit]');
        var emailButton = j$('[id$=btnEmail]');
        var shippingMethod = j$('[id$=shippingMethod]');
        var alternateAddress = j$('[id$=chkbxAlternateAddress]');
        var alternateStreet = j$('[id$=alternateaddress]');
        var alternateCity = j$('[id$=alternatecity]');
        var alternateState = j$('[id$=alternatestate]');
        var alternateZip = j$('[id$=alternatezip]');
        submitButton.click(function(e){
            j$('[id$=documentQuantity]').each(function(index){
                if(j$(this).text() == '0') {
                    j$("#contentQtyError").css({"display":"inline"});
                    j$(this).parent().parent().css({"background-color":"#FFFFCC"});
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });             
            if(shippingMethod.val() == '') {
                shippingMethod.after("<span class='shippingMethodErrorMsg'>Error: A Shipping Method is Required</span>");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                j$(".shippingMethodErrorMsg").remove();
            }
            if(alternateAddress.attr("checked")) {
                alternateStreet.after("<span class='alternateStreetErrorMsg'>Error: A Street Address is Required</span>");
                alternateCity.after("<span class='alternateCityErrorMsg'>Error: A City is Required</span>");
                alternateState.after("<span class='alternateStateErrorMsg'>Error: A State is Required</span>");
                alternateZip.after("<span class='alternateZipErrorMsg'>Error: A Zip is Required</span>");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                j$(".alternateStreetErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateCityErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateStateErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateZipErrorMsg").remove();
            }
        });
        shippingMethod.change(function(){
            if(shippingMethod.val() == 'Email') {
                emailButton.css({"display":""});
                submitButton.css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerAltAddressToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxAlternateAddress]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=alternateAddressPanel]').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerCustomKitToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxCustomKit]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=customKitPanel]').css({"display":"none"});             
                j$('#containerPersonalNoteToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxPersonalNote]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('[id$=personalNotePanel]').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('#containerFollowUpTaskToggle').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=chkbxScheduleTask]').attr('checked',false);
                j$('#recurrence').css({"display":"none"});
                j$('[id$=commentsBlock]').css({"display":"none"});
            }
            else {
                emailButton.css({"display":"none"});
                submitButton.css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerAltAddressToggle').css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerCustomKitToggle').css({"display":""});                
                j$('#containerPersonalNoteToggle').css({"display":""});
                j$('#containerFollowUpTaskToggle').css({"display":""}); 
                j$('[id$=nextTask]').val("");   
                j$('[id$=commentsBlock]').css({"display":""});      
            }                           
        });
        alternateAddress.change(function() {
            if(alternateAddress.attr("checked") != "checked") {
                j$(".alternateStreetErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateCityErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateStateErrorMsg").remove();
                j$(".alternateZipErrorMsg").remove();
            }
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Assuming you still want the button click to do something on subsequent clicks, just use a variable to keep track of whether or not you've already done the html insertion.

Comment: please post relevent code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the inserted html in a div with a specific id using `.wrap()`

and then on your click do something like this:

```
if ($('#idofwrap').length == 0) {
    //wrap content and insert here
}
```

or put each of your afters in an if eg:

```
if ($('.alternateStreetErrorMsg').length == 0) {
    alternateStreet.after("<span class='alternateStreetErrorMsg'>Error: A Street Address is Required</span>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a boolean in the scope of submitButton.Click(...). check the boolean in submitButton.Click(...). the ref to that boolean will be saved in the function associated to submitButton.Click(...) as part of that function's closure.

Even prettier, create a decorator function to save the boolean in its closure so you do not pollute the parent namespace with your boolean:

```
submitButton.Click(
(function() { 
var notDoneYet = true; 
return function(){/** function to insert the html, checking notDoneYet**/}
})()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initaialize any global variable say `var i = 0;` and in the function which executes to insert html , put that inside `if(i<1)` and inside if do `i++` . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.one()`

```
$("elem").one("click", function() {
    //only runs once!
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Although it's really hard to tell what the OP wants from their code dump, I believe they still want the button click to do *something*, just not insert the html again on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check size like

```
if ($('.classofspan').size() == 0) {
//add span
}
```